# missing 1 required positional argument: '....'

Tags: python

I'm fairly new in python and was wondering why I get this error message:

```
AlphaVantage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'symbol'
```

The program is meant to fetch API data that I want to be updated every 10 seconds. That's why I'm trying to use the scheduler.
Thanks, in advance.

Code is below:

```
import schedule
import time

from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Updating stocks...")

#Your Key
key = ''

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
    ts = TimeSeries(key)
    data = ts.get_intraday(symbol, interval='1min')

    print(str(data))

#What Stock
AlphaVantage('AMD')

def job():
   print("I'm working...")



#Timer on updates
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(AlphaVantage)

while 1:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I guess that when `schedule.every().seconds.do(AlphaVantage)` calls `AlphaVantage` is not passing it's required param

Comment: Your missing the argument on the #Timer on updates

Comment: Sorry i was to fast when i wrote it into Stack. schedule.every(10).seconds.do(AlphaVantage), but still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

From [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-the-job-function) documentation:

```
schedule.every().seconds.do(AlphaVantage, symbol='AMD')
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem!